# Compute the mean of certain elements per group?

Tags: r

If I have this data:

```
                                                       dat=structure(list(Mod = c("ACC", "NCC", "DCC","CCC", 
                       "ACC", "NCC", "DCC","CCC"), Mean = c(33, 
                                                                     48,33, 42, 28, 48,28, 
                                                                     51), var = c("HF", "HF", "HF", "HF","F", "F","F", 
                                                                                                "F")), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to compute the mean of all Mod except ACC and CCC per var (assign that to all).

Desired output

```
Mod Mean var
All   40.5  HF
ACC   33  HF
CCC   42  HF
All   38   F
ACC   28   F
CCC   51   F
```

Answer (score 1):

My crack at it:

```
library(dplyr)
dat$category <- "all"
dat2 <- dat[dat$Mod=="ACC",]
dat2$category <- "ACC"
dat3 <- dat[dat$Mod=="CCC",]
dat3$category <- "CCC"

mydat <- data.table::rbindlist(list(dat, dat2, dat3)) 
data.table::setDF(mydat)
mydat <- as_tibble(mydat)
res <- mydat %>% group_by(category, var) %>% summarise(mymean=mean(Mean)) %>% arrange(across(category))
res

# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   category [3]
  category var   mymean
  <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
1 ACC      F       28  
2 ACC      HF      33  
3 all      F       42.3
4 all      HF      41  
5 CCC      F       51  
6 CCC      HF      42
```

Comment: Perhaps just remove the across?